# user-input validation by reg exp on WPF textbox

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, validation, user-input

I have an array of input validations.
Each row of the array represents a single input validation; a string of the regular expression check and a string to display for the user in case the validation went bad:

```
public class myClass
{
     public static string[][] inputsInfo = new string[4][];

     static myClass()
     {
     // ID - 9 digits
     inputsInfo[0] = new string[2] { "^[0-9]{9}$", "exactly 9 digits (0-9)" };

     // only letters and possibly more than one word
     inputsInfo[1] = new string[2] { "^[A-Za-z]{2,}(( )[A-Za-z]{2,})*$", "only letters (A-Z) or (a-z)" };

     // Number - unlimited digits
     inputsInfo[2] = new string[2] { "^[0-9]+$", "only digits (0-9)" };

     // username, password
     inputsInfo[3] = new string[2] { "^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,}$", "at least 6 characters.\nOnly letters (A-Z) or (a-z) and digits (0-9) are allowed" };

     }
..............
..............
}
```

I have windows which contain WPF textboxes. There are fields which have the same input validation, and that's why i want to save all the input validations in the array, so i can just select the validation i need at the moment.

I have this form:

```
...............

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="First name"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="firstName" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="Search"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Last name"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="lastName" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Content="Search"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="ID number"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="ID" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Content="Search"/>

...............
```

Each textbox has a near button with a Click event.
How can i perform an input validation by a button click?

Is there a way doing that by XAML code?
or only in the code-behind by c# code?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: does someone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i perform an input validation by a button click?

Why not create Boolean flags on the ViewModel which monitor the target textbox's bound text property for validation. Example

VM:

```
public string FirstName { get { return _firstName; }
                          set { _firstname = value; 
                                PropertyChanged("IsFirstNameValid");
                                PropertyChanged("FirstName");
                              }
                        }

public bool IsFirstNameValid { get { return Regex.IsMatch( FirstName,
                                                           ValidationPatternFirstName); }}
```

XAML

```
<TextBox x:Name="firstName" 
         Text={Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

Then on any change to the stored value `FirstName` the Boolean value `IsFirstNameValid` will accurately reflect that status when later accessed.

Also you can bind to `IsFirstNameValid` on the screen to show an icon or not and it will be updated per its status.